# Is it ok to Text After Kriyat Shema al Hamita?

Tags: halacha, shema, sleep, speech-talking, phone

Is it okay to text after saying kriyat shema al hamita?

You're not supposed to talk afterward, as it says:

> Tremble and sin not. Reflect in your hearts while on your beds, and be utterly silent.

-Artscroll

Does texting count as talking though?

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Comment: Kitzur SA: וּלְאַחַר שֶׁאָמַר בִּרְכַּת הַמַּפִּיל, לֹא יֹאכַל וְלֹא יִשְׁתֶּה וְלֹא יְדַבֵּר עַד שֶׁיִּישַׁן -

Comment: Do you text in the morning before saying Haamavir Sheinah? If so, then what's the difference?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60344/759